# GWT server part?

Tags: gwt

I'm thinking about an application where in some cases both client and server would run on customer's computer. Concerning the client's resource usage I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539885/memory-usage-of-a-gwt-application), concerning the general disadvantages of GWT I've found [this](http://confusion.tweakblogs.net/blog/1052/the-disadvantages-of-the-google-web-toolkit.html), but I can't find anything about the overhead of the server part. I need no application server there, anything capable of running the server part of GWT would do.

What is needed to run the server part of GWT and how many resources it consumes?

Comment: your question as it stands covers scenarios from 1-2 user mirco-app to facebook monsters. please be **much** more specific.

Comment: It should be a small app, at least in this scenario. I'm basically asking about the *minimum* resources needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a ServiceImpl w/ your GWT app, you need to deploy it into a servlet container, like Tomcat or Jetty (or many others). Otherwise, it can be deployed on any web server, as it will only consist of javascript, HTML, and CSS.